# C# - Exclude member from for loop

Tags: c#

I want to see if the red drone entered the green drone's safe area or vice-versa. **My problem is that the debug shows that drone0 entered in drone1 safe area and drone1 entered drone0 safe area. I only want to check once.**

[image]

How do I exclude repetition so I only need to check once?

```
 for(int i=0; i<drone.Length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<drone.Length;j++)
            {
                if (i == j) continue;

                else if(drone[i].pos_atual().X <= drone[j].pos_atual().X +distancia &&
                   drone[i].pos_atual().X >= drone[j].pos_atual().X - distancia &&
                   drone[i].pos_atual().Y <= drone[j].pos_atual().Y + distancia &&
                   drone[i].pos_atual().Y >= drone[j].pos_atual().Y - distancia)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(i + "joined " + j +"safe area");
                }
            }
        }
```

Variables: int distancia is 20
pos_atual means actual position

EDIT:

The answered question **always gives me that drone0 entered drone1's safe area even tho it was drone1 that entered drone0's safe area**

Comment: For the second loop, start it for i+1, eg the one on from yourself, so you only ever check items you havent already checked.

Comment: you're smart. i think i will work.

Comment: movement is relative. unless you define that green=motionless and red=moving, entering; and expose a property on the drone object to indicate this, it will not be possible to tell "which one entered".

Comment: then you have to change the drone "move" action to include the check, so you check then if IT moves into someone elses range, not if all the others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I suggest you to move checking whether other drone in safe area of current drone to drone class.
2. I would also to stick only coordinates verification. I.e. later you will be able to check whether any other object is in safe area of drone.
3. You should not check rectangles when verifying safety area. I assume it should be circle.

Drone class:

```
public class Drone
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public Point Location { get; }
    public int SafeAreaRange { get; } // can be constant

    public bool SafeAreaContains(Point location)
    {
        var dx = Math.Abs(Location.X - location.X);
        var dy = Math.Abs(Location.Y - location.Y);
        var distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(dy, 2) + Math.Pow(dx, 2));
        return distance < SafeAreaRange;
    }
}
```

Now if you have list of drones and want to check which are entered other drones safe area. First case - all drones have same size of safe area. That means if drone A in safe area of drone B, then drone B is also in safe area of drone A. You can skip second check here. As @Manfred suggested:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < drones.Count - 1; i++)
 {
     for(int j = i + 1; j < drones.Count; j++)
     {
         if (drones[i].SafeAreaContains(drones[j].Location))
            Debug.WriteLine($"{i} joined {j} safe area");
     }
 }
```

If drones can have different safe area sizes:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < drones.Count; i++)
 {
     for(int j = 0; j < drones.Count; j++)
     {
         if (i == j)
             continue;

         if (drones[i].SafeAreaContains(drones[j].Location))
            Debug.WriteLine($"{i} joined {j} safe area");
     }
 }
```

---

And last - if you will assign `Id` to drones instead of relying on indexes in list, your code can be

```
 var intersections = from a in drones
                     from b in drones
                     where a.Id != b.Id && a.SafeAreaContains(b)
                     select new { DroneId = a.Id, InvaderId = b.Id };

 foreach(var i in intersections)
     Debug.WriteLine($"{i.InvaderId} joined {i.DroneId} safe area");
```

Comment: But I wanted to know who entered the safe area of who because I need to send a command to the drone that entered to leave it. like stay outside the safe area

Comment: @TiagoSilva if both drones are moving, who entered the safe area of who?

Comment: You're right. I will try your code now and reply soon. Thx for the help.

Comment: I also need to know how to draw a circle as safe area. That's a chart. I was just drawing Lines on the graph

Comment: your code seems to work well. I'm using Location and Desired_Location. Imagine the drone goes inside a safe area. How can I tell him to stay outside that safe area? I need to give him a new Desired_Location but which one?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to modify your loops, this would work for any combination where you don't need duplicate conditions:

```
for(int i = 0; i < drone.Length - 1; i++)
{
    for(int j = i+1; j < drone.Length; j++)
    {
        // etc.
```

The loop above will limit the iterations from `i` and `j` so that `j` is always bigger than `i` so you can remove `if (i == j) continue;` too.

---

A couple of notes not directly related to your question.

- A rectangular safe-zone doesn't make a lot of sense for drones.
- This check only works if the safe-zones of all elements have the same size, shape and orientation.

Comment: I still have a problem. How do I know if drone0 entered drone1 safe area or the contrary? I want to know who entered.

Comment: Because your way always gives me that drone0 entered drone1's safe area even tho it was drone1 that entered drone0's safe area

Comment: then define "entered", is there a property on the drone object (kind of a friend/foe marker)? and add requirement to question or ask another question.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, sorry

Comment: I can only ask questions every 90 minutes. I think it's relatable to my problem.

Comment: Manfred can you help me with my question?